# apostrophes: Possessive

Tags: punctuation, possessives

> The addiction of drugs is bad for both mental and physical health.

Or it can be written as

> The drugs' addiction is bad for both mental and physical's health.

Is the second sentence using apostrophes is a correct replacement for the first sentence. I'm a little confused; in which manner or situation the possession of nouns using apostrophes are needed to take care

Comment: You aren't addicted **of** drugs... you're addicted **to** drugs. Drugs may be said to have addictive powers but I don't know that the first sentence is really idiomatic at all.

Comment: The most natural way to say it is *Drug addiction (is bad for both mental and physical health)*.

Comment: @clare and if we write it as: Drug's addiction is bad for both mental and physical health. Is it incorrect w.r.t grammar and rules.

Comment: A native speaker of English would not say/write *Drug's addiction*.

Comment: The drugs aren't addicted to anything. When you say "drug's addiction" that's what it sounds like you mean.

Answer (score 1):

In English there are two common forms of the possessive, as you've mentioned.  First we have

> The brother of Frank is named Steve

and also

> Frank's brother is named Steve

Both would be understood, but the second is much more commonly used. The first is mostly used in formal speech and writing. As for your example:

> The addiction of drugs.

To me (a native American English speaker) the reason why the substitution doesn't work here is that "of drugs" seems to be acting as a prepositional phrase, not a possessive. This would sound more correct if said as:

> The addiction **to** drugs is bad for both mental and physical health.

As has been mentioned in the comments, though, English does have a phrase '**Drug addiction**' which means 'the addiction to drugs', and sounds much more natural in use.  All together, the correct sentence would be:

> Drug addiction is bad for both mental and physical health.